# Community effort questions banner repeated

Tags: bug, post-notices

On this question: [What technical details should a programmer of a web application consider before making the site public?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/46716/173647)

[image]

Community effort questions banner is repeated.

Chrome: stable

Android: 5/6/7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question's [timeline](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/46716/timeline) shows two users added the same notice on the same evening. So it's a data problem, not a UI problem. [Here](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/60849/12622) is an example from last year (with a different type of post notice); that seems to be have been a [race condition](https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/60849/timeline).

There are 50 posts in the network which are affected by this, as [this SEDE query shows](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/1506359/posts-with-duplicate-notices-networkwide). Most of them on Movies & TV. I presume the moderators can solve these instances by removing and reapplying the locks.

Comment: So only way to fix this is that bulky way? No bots like the community one or other tag one?

Comment: I never said it was a UI bug. No concern, just letting you know.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy ofcourse someone could write a script that community could then execute, but seeing the low amount of affected posts it would be far quicker to do this manually. Either by site mods or a staff member.

Comment: @Luuklag then, notify this to staff? not right now.

Answer (score 6):

From the [timeline](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/46716/timeline) of that post it becomes obvious that the notice was added twice:

[image: Screenshot of post timeline showing two instances of the post wiki notice being added.]

Comment: Thanks for the visual, but the other one contains more info...